# Can I plug USBasp to an outlet via cellphone charger adapter and therefore power my standalone ATmega328p?

Tags: power-supply, atmega, usbasp

I wanted to power my circuit (ATmega, 2 LEDs and crystal) but I do not really want to use batteries. Can I just plug USBasp into cellphone charger (5V - 1A) and then with plugged USBasp power my circuit? Will USBasp decrese the current or ATmega (or both!) will be fried? Or just overheated or something.

Comment: You could, but it makes more sense to ditch the USBASP AVR programmer between the USB charger and the ATmega and power the ATmega from the USB charger directly. The USB supply voltage is 5 V, just what the ATmega needs.

Comment: But USBasp provides me easy access to every single pin. I cannot access VCC and GND from standard USB cable, now can I?

Answer (score 2):

You could, but it makes more sense to ditch the USBASP AVR programmer between the USB charger and the ATmega altogether, and power the ATmega from the USB charger directly. The USB supply voltage is 5 V, just what the ATmega needs.

If the charger has a removable cable you can just take some old USB cable, cut off the slave side (B, mini-B, micro-B) connector, remove the insulation and hook up the GND and Vcc (5 V) lines. The data lines should be left unconnected.

[image]

Comment: But you are sure that this 1A input will not be too much for the controller?

Comment: @AdrianDąbek The maximum output current doesn't matter as long as it's greater than what your device draws at most. You could operate the ATmega from a 1000 A power supply if you wanted to, as long as it's 5 V. The USB charger only supplies 1 A *if the device connected to it draws that much*.

Comment: Oooow! That's how it works then. Forgive me the ameteurness. At least I learnt something. Thanks again.